# Need a little bit of guidance with stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

> Let $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
>         cos(t) + N(t)\\
>         sin(t) + S(t)\\
>          \end{bmatrix} $ (where $N(t)$ is a gaussian process and S(t) is a Poisson's process).
>
> Let $Y(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
>         2 & 4\\
>         6 & 8\\
>          \end{bmatrix} X(t)$. Evaluate $E[Y(t)]$ and $R_y(t_1,t_2)$.

This is an extra exercise, but out of curiosity I would like to know how to solve it.

First I evaluated $Y(t)$

$Y(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
        2cos(t) + 4sin(t) +2N(t)+4S(t)\\
        6cos(t) + 8sin(t) +6N(t)+8S(t) \\
         \end{bmatrix}$

My question is how do I evaluate $E[Y(t)]$. Should I evaluate $E[Y_1(t)]$ and $E[Y_2(t)]$ separately?

Also what does $R_y(t_1,t_2)$? Is that the covariance function (cause this exercise has different notation from what I've seen)?

Comment: YEs, $R_y(t_1,t_2)$ is the covariance function for $Y(t)$ in times $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to evaluate $E[Y(t)]$?